# Have zipped this , and need it on a format [x1, y1]

Tags: python-2.7

Have a problem, i have zipped two lists. Now u see this:

```
[(1951, 720)]
[(1927, 107000)]
[(1952, 1914)]
[(1976, 780)]
[(1902, 4239)]
[(1919, 910)]
```

How can i get it on this format:

```
[1976, 780]
[1902, 4239]
[1919, 910]
```

I have made the lists like this:

```
mass.append((int(data[i]['mass'])))

year.append(int(str(data[p]['year'])))
```

UPDATE;

Still dosen't work:

My code so far are here:

```
import json
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

json_data = open('meteors.json')

data = json.load(json_data)


year = []
for p in range(0, 1180):

    if data[p]['year'] != "":
        year.append(str(data[p]['year']))


mass = []
for i in range(0, 1180):

    if data[i]['mass'] != 0:
        mass.append((str(data[i]['mass'])))
        #mass.sort()
        if year > '1900':
            print year


year_and_mass = zip(year, mass)
print [(year_and_mass)]

#for v in year_and_mass:
    #print map(year_and_mass, v)

#for item in itertools.izip(year, mass):

#for item in zip(year, mass):
    #print [item]
    #for v in item:
        #print map(item, v)
#for v in item:
    #
    #print map(item, v)
```

so i still get the same format as in the top as i wrote., also as u can see i tried map command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get generate text in the format \[x1 , y1\] \[x2, y2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149809/how-to-get-generate-text-in-the-format-x1-y1-x2-y2)

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of lists instead of a list of tuples? Then, `map(list, zip(year, mass))`

Comment: @falsetru - I think you hit the nail on the head. After the fact you can still do this: `newList = map(list, accidentalZipTuples)`

Comment: @Floris, What does `hit the nail on the head` means ?  I'm not good at English.  I doubt it really mean this: http://images.sodahead.com/polls/002216527/5934913973_istockphoto_280569_nail_head_answer_2_xlarge.jpeg

Comment: @falsetrue Ah - sorry. It is a compliment. You have a problem ('need to drive nail into wood'). You have a tool ('hammer'). You solve your problem ('boom - hammer hits nail. problem solved.). Make sense?

Comment: @Floris, Thank you for kind explanation. You don't need to be sorry.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_the_nail_on_the_head : "To identify something exactly; to arrive at exactly the right answer."

Comment: @Floris, I didn't know the flat part of the nail is called *head*. My native language also call it *head* (I also didn't know this.). Now it's very clear. Thank you, again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Having read both this and your earlier question, it seems to me you actually want to get to a text representation of your data - where your data is originally in a list of tuples.

This is best done by iterating over the list and printing out in the format you actually need. If you started out with

```
myData = [[(1,2)],[(3,4)],[(4,5)]]
```

Then a simple `print myData` gives you

```
[[(1, 2)], [(3, 4)], [(4, 5)]]
```

Trying to iterate, you might do

```
for v in myData:
  print v
```

Which results in:

```
[(1, 2)]
[(3, 4)]
[(4, 5)]
```

which is what you were showing.  Now, if instead you did

```
for v in myData:
  print map(list, v)
```

You get

```
[[1, 2]]
[[3, 4]]
[[4, 5]]
```

*Almost* what you want, but one too many square brackets. And so you find your solution:

```
for v in myData:
  print map(list, v)[0]
```

with the result:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
```

I believe this takes you from "what you have" to "what you need". I admit that without the comments from @truefalse I would not have done this - but it was really only after reading the other question you posed that I put this together.

For future reference - it is better to edit / improve your question, rather than ask a new one...